# How to add a "Read more" button to my blog?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have an HTML template which I convert to a Wordpress theme, but i can't add a **"Read more"** button to the home page.

I use the following code in functions.php:

```
function the_content_limit($max_char, $more_link_text = '(more...)', $stripteaser = 0, $more_file = '') {
    $content = get_the_content($more_link_text, $stripteaser, $more_file);
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = strip_tags($content);

    if (strlen($_GET['p']) > 0) {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>";
    }
    else if ((strlen($content)>$max_char) && ($espacio = strpos($content, " ", $max_char ))) {
        $content = substr($content, 0, $espacio);
        $content = $content;
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "...";
        echo "</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>";
        echo $content;
        echo "</p>";
    }
}
```

I also use the following code in index.php:

```
<div class="text_home"><?php the_content_limit(300); ?></div>
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: The question is completely unclear as to what it aims to accomplish.

Comment: "read more" is not appear in home page

Answer (score 1):

```
   //keep this code in function.php
 function get_excerpt($limit=10, $content) {


      $content = explode(' ', $content,$limit);

      if (count($content)>=$limit) {

        array_pop($content);

        $content = implode(" ",$content);
        $content = $content.' ...';
      } else {

        $content = implode(" ",$content);

      } 

      return $content;

    }
```

where you want to call this function

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = strip_tags($content);
echo get_excerpt(15, $content);
```

Comment: any issue comment here.

Comment: i want call this function in index.php, do i add this code:

Comment: Yes you will add get_excerpt to  functions.php and then you will be able to call in index.php

Comment: i do this, but a problem is don't solve ! my problem is (this a word "read more" is not appear in home page" )

Comment: please clear me one thing function calling not working in your index.php?

Comment: sorry, i can't understand your comment !

Comment: if you want read more text then this is very simple. where you call get_excerpt  function. Add if condition. means if($content > $limit) add read more link <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>">read more</a>